# Evaluate limits of differntiable function at x=1.

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
$f$ is differentiable on $x=1$ and $f(1)>0$ . Evaluate the limits:

a. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac {f(1+\frac 1n)}{f(1)}\right)^{\frac 1n}$$

b. $$\lim_{x \to 1} \left(\frac {f(x)}{f(1)}\right)^{\frac 1{\log x}}$$

**What I did:**
on a, if i evaluate "naively" it turns out the limit is $1^0=1$. But it seems too simple to be true...
on b, tried using the exponent trick, but I couldn't manage to eliminate the $\ln x$ that screws up the limit.
I don't know what I can do with the info about the function being differentiable in $1$, except maybe using the definition...

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(1+\frac{1}{n})\sim_\infty f(1)+ \frac{f'(1)}{n}$ and $\log(1+x)\sim_0 x$ then
$$\left(\frac {f(1+\frac 1n)}{f(1)}\right)^{\frac 1n}=\exp\left(\frac 1n\log\left(\frac {f(1+\frac 1n)}{f(1)}\right)\right)\sim_\infty\exp\left(\frac{f'(1)}{f(1)n^2}\right)\to 1$$

By the same method we have
$$\left(\frac {f(x)}{f(1)}\right)^{\frac 1{\log x}}=\exp\left(\frac 1{\log x}\log\left(\frac {f(x)}{f(1)}\right)\right)\sim_1 \exp\left(\frac 1{\log x}\left(\frac{f'(1)}{f(1)}(x-1)\right)\right)\sim_1\exp\left(\frac{f'(1)}{f(1)}\right)$$

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but I don't understand what the tilde sign means here... (3rd step on a and on b)

Comment: Anyone can explain that tilde sign please?

Comment: Let $f$ and $g$ two function and $a\in \mathbb R$ if $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ then we write $f(x)\sim_a g(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$f\left(1+\cfrac{1}{n}\right)=f(1)+f'(1)\cfrac{1}{n}+o\left(\cfrac{1}{n}\right)$